# I am looking for this font

Tags: fonts, label

They used this font on a simple clothing label. But I couldn't find it on the internet, paid or free. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like a font. The inconsistencies and misalignment make it look hand drawn

Comment: It's a monospace font - like the kind you'd find on a typewriter.  The image you posted is too small and low res to get an exact match using automated font ID sites.  You may have to just go through lists of similar fonts until you find something close.